# Get only text direction from google map api in android programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I didn't want to draw route from one place to another.Is it possible that I can fetch only text directions
Like for javascript api [google javascript api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Also are you asking a question towards Google Maps Javascript API or Android API?

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Map Intent. This uses the official Maps Application.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?"+
        “saddr=location_start”+
        "daddr=location_end"));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
"com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent)
```

> Intents let you start an activity in another app by describing a simple action you'd like to perform (such as "display a map" or "show directions to the airport") in an Intent object.

Please see this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents) for more information.

But if you only want a text result and do not want to call the official Map application, then use the [Maps Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)